# [UT][Catch2] Several test cases or one with several sections

Tags: unit-testing, class, testing, automated-tests, catch2

Let's say we want to test one file (or class). What should be better approach (always? maybe in special cases?)?

Framework *Catch2*: https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2

1. **Several test cases**

```
TEST_CASE("First", "[some_details]")
{
  Class obj;

  REQUIRE(obj.firstFunction() == 1);
}

TEST_CASE("Second", "[some_details]")
{
  Class obj;

  REQUIRE(obj.secondFunction() == 1);
}

TEST_CASE("Third", "[some_details]")
{
  Class obj;

  REQUIRE(obj.thirdFunction() == 1);
}
```

2. **One test case with several sections**

```
TEST_CASE("Check functions", "[some_details]")
{
  Class obj;

  SECTION("First", "[some_details]")
  {
    REQUIRE(obj.firstFunction() == 1);
  }

  SECTION("Second", "[some_details]")
  {
    REQUIRE(obj.secondFunction() == 1);
  }

  SECTION("Third", "[some_details]")
  {
    REQUIRE(obj.thirdFunction() == 1);
  }
}
```

I think we ought to use `TEST_CASE` for each functionality separately (if it is possible). If it's not then we can use `SECTION` in case of some dependence. I also think that `SECTION` are good when we want to check several outputs from one function, for example:

```
TEST_CASE("Check function first", "[some_details]")
{
  Class obj;

  SECTION("Positive", "[some_details]")
  {
    REQUIRE(obj.firstFunction() == 1);
  }

  SECTION("Negative", "[some_details]")
  {
    REQUIRE(obj.firstFunction() == 0);
  }
}
```

What's your opinion? Which approach is better (and when)? You got some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is:

Using TEST_CASE you can test each case individually. With SECTION this is not possible in some IDEs (like CLION.

Comment: What you mean by "feature to execute only a specific SECTION"? You thought about how to run exact section, like it is mentioned here: https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/command-line.md#specify-the-section-to-run

Comment: In my example above in step 2 TEST_CASE run three times, once for each section.

Comment: You are right on the command line it is possible. In my IDE (CLION it is not yet possible..)